# Convertir una formula matemática a código

Tags: javascript, math

La formula es **P= F/(1+r)^n**

**pseudocódigo**

1 Display "Enter the desired future value."

2 Input futureValue

3 Display "Enter the annual interest rate."

4 Input rate

5 Display "How many years will you let the money grow?"

6 Input years

7 Set presentValue = futureValue / (1 + rate)^years

8 Display "You will need to deposit $", presentValue

La **F** es la variable *futureVaule*

```
var futureVaule = prompt("Enter the desired future value.");
```

La **R** es la variable rate

```
var rate = prompt("Enter the annual interest rate.");
```

Y el **^n** es la variable años

```
var years = prompt("How many years will you let the money grow?");
```

Y asi es como coloque la formula pero no me sale la respuesta correcta

```
var presentVaule = parseInt(futureVaule)/(1 + parseInt(rate))**parseInt(years);
var total = document.write("You will need to deposit $" + presentVaule);
```

Comment: Creo que te falta un par de  paréntesis: `parseInt(futureVaule)/((1 + parseInt(rate))**parseInt(years));`

Comment: De hecho a su fómula también el falta un peréntesis, aunque parace ser que el que falta es el cierre del divisor. Un ejemplo con valores y resultado esperado no estaría mal, pero con las observaciones del compañero @FranAcuna parace ser suficiente.

Comment: **P= F/(1+r)^n** perdón esa es la formula

Comment: Depende la potencia vaya aplicada a quien... Podría ser `P = (F / (1+r)) ^ n` o poría ser `P = F / ((1+r) ^ n)`. Cual de las 2 es la formula correcta?

Comment: Hice así pero no me sirve, es para una tarea de la U, ahi esta con una guía de instrucciones que me dio mi profesor. El en la **primera variable** le coloco 10000, **en el segundo** 0.05 que es el 5% y en la potencia que es año coloco 10 y la respuesta tiene que salir **6139**

Comment: Y  me sale 10000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas tratando de parsear el rate(tengo entendido que es el porcentaje) a un int. entonces por alli va el error. Estas le estas pasando 0.05 a parseInt. Entonces alli esta el problema. Eso te esta devolviendo 0.

Bastara parsear el rate como float. utilizando parseFloat(rate)

Aqui un ejemplo que da el resultado esperado

```js
var futureVaule = prompt("Enter the desired future value.");

var rate = prompt("Enter the annual interest rate.");

var years = prompt("How many years will you let the money grow?");

var presentVaule = parseInt(futureVaule)/(1 + parseFloat(rate))**parseInt(years);


var total = document.write("You will need to deposit $" + presentVaule);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Pero si no quiero los decimales?¿Que tengo que hacer?

Comment: Si quieres puros números enteros puedes usar `Math.floor(presentVaule)`

Comment: Si verdad, me hiciste acordar de esa funcion. Gracias bro.